# Firefox Okta integration, setting up Agentless DSSO

Tags: windows, firefox, single-sign-on, okta, ntlm

I am currently using trying to set up DSSO with Okta utilizing Firefox. I have been able to successfully set up Edge/Chrome/IE on the domain without issue. I have set the following documentation as outlined on the Okta website for setting up Firefox to no avail. We have been troubleshooting with the Okta experts for the last three days with no forward progress, so I figured I would post the information available here:

1. Firefox version 107.0.1 32-bit
2. TLS 1.2
3. NTLM v2
4. Windows Server 2019

the result that the agentlessDssoPrecheck is returning:

`{"result" : "FAIL_NTMLSSP"}` - (that is not a misspelling; the return should be NTLM, but whatever)

I have the following options set in Firefox:

> network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris.  **org.kerberos.okta.com**
>
> network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris  **org.kerberos.okta.com**
>
> network.negotiate-auth.allow-non-fqdn **true**
>
> network.negotiate-auth.allow-proxies **true**
>
> network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris  **org.kerberos.okta.com**
>
> network.automatic-auth.allow-non-fqdn **true**

I attempted to pull the logs using set NSPR_LOG_MODULES=negotiateauth:5, but while Firefox does create the log, it doesn't write anything, including the failure to the log. (If I set the value to all:5, I get a ton of information, it appears useless for what I am trying to troubleshoot)

I attempted to pull fiddler and Wireshark information; I haven't set up the decoding on the Wireshark portion yet; however, I did get an extract of the fiddler information, but I didn't spot anything in there that seemed to indicate why the failure was occurring.

I have one suspicion; the following option in both Edge and Chrome has been set:  **DisableAuthNegotiateCnameLookup = enable** - I don't see an option like that in Firefox or something similar to be able to adjust that value.

Some additional information to share:

Firefox is connecting to and submitting an authentication message to org.kerberos.okta.com; however, it appears to be in the wrong format.

> """Received authorization header contains raw NTLM token, will fail
> precheck. Okta is not getting Kerberos ticket but raw NTLM token
> instead."""

Answer (score 0):

Firefox with Kerberos can be sensitive to reverse name lookups.

For testing purposes have you tried to set a manual entry in the hosts file with an entry to return the correct DNS name?

I would be interested to know your results from Wireshark using the following filter

dns || Kerberos

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have not, I am happy to try it! So I am tracking on your recommendation are you saying to do the following in the hosts file:

IP_ADDRESS DOMAIN_NAME
0.0.0.0 org.kerberos.okta.com

Comment: Its a longshot, but based on your "kerberos" URL being org.kerberos.okta.com  I would do a public lookup for that address, and then create a host file entry using those detail.  ipAddress org.kerberos.okta.com

Comment: Hi Bob, Ignore that, I got onto a machine to test. and can't get it to work either.  Also tried network.auth.use-sspi option to False which is recommended/required for Citrix and Kerberos.  That didn't work either.